# Angular 2: Meu componente não funciona na index

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Eu gostaria de interpretar minha componente  dentro da minha index.html, about.html, contact.html, entre outras páginas.

Criei o componente  usando o Angular cli.

A minha estrutura esta da seguinte forma:
[image: Estrutura do meu projeto Angular]

O código dentro do meu arquivo **app.module.ts** é:

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarModule } from './navbar/navbar.module';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    NavbarModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Em meu **app.components**, eu nem mexi.

No meu arquivo **navbar.module.ts** esta assim:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    NavbarComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    NavbarComponent
  ]
})
export class NavbarModule { }
```

Já o meu arquivo **navbar-components** está assim:

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Dentro do meu arquivo navbar.component.html tem meus que gostaria de importar na index. E na index.html, estou tentando chamar a minha componenet , mas não vai.

Preciso de alguma solução, por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insira a tag
 
dentro do app.component.html
que funcionará.

Comment: Sim... depois eu tive que me atentar sobre os conceitos de rotas para uso das tags. Obrigado Guilherme.

Answer (score 0):

Usa esse selector pra colocar ela la dentro
No seu caso,na linha onde deseja colocar a nav use

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
```